# Value of props is empty when I try and pass a variable to my modal in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm building an inventory system at my work, and I have a table that lists all the inventory items.  I can then click on a row of the table and retrieve the information about that specific item.  What I'm trying to implement is a modal that pops up with that items information, but the issue I'm having is that no information is being passed to my modal for some reason.

When I click on a row in the items table, and console log the result, I get back the necessary fields that my modal should contain, but when the modal opens all the fields are empty.

Here is the code for my modal

```js
import React from 'react';

export default class InventoryModal extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            Item: this.props.item,
            ID: this.props.item.ID,
            CreatedBy: this.props.item.ID,
            DateCreated: this.props.item.DateCreated,
            Description: this.props.item.Description,
            Location: this.props.item.Location,
            ModelNumber: this.props.item.ModelNumber,
            Serial: this.props.item.Serial,
            PartNumber: this.props.item.PartNumber,
            PartName: this.props.item.PartName,
            Price: this.props.item.Price,
            QuantityOnHand: this.props.item.QuantityOnHand,
            ReorderPoint: this.props.item.ReorderNumber,
            Type: this.props.item.Type,
            Units: this.props.item.Units,
            Vendor: this.props.item.Vendor,
        }
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        console.log("item passed in: " + JSON.stringify(this.state.Item));
        //this.PullDataFromDatabase();
    }

    PullDataFromDatabase(){
        //console.log(this.state.Item);
        var item = this.state.Item;
        this.RenderContent(item);

        this.setState({ID: item.ID,
                        CreatedBy: item.CreatedBy,
                        DateCreated: item.DateCreated,
                        Description: item.Description,
                        Location: item.Location,
                        ModelNumber: item.ModelNumber,
                        Serial: item.Serial,
                        PartNumber: item.PartNumber,
                        PartName: item.PartName,
                        Price: item.Price,
                        QuantityOnHand: item.QuantityOnHand,
                        ReorderPoint: item.ReorderPoint,
                        Type: item.Type,
                        Units: item.Units,
                        Vendor: item.Vendor,
        })
    }

    OnChangeHandler(e){
        switch(e.target.id){
            case 'partname': this.setState({PartName: e.target.value})
                break;
            case 'description': this.setState({Description: e.target.value})
                break;
            case 'location': this.setState({Location: e.target.value})
                break;
            case 'modelnumber': this.setState({ModelNumber: e.target.value})
                break;
            case 'partnumber': this.setState({PartNumber: e.target.value})
                break;
            case 'serialnumber': this.setState({Serial: e.target.value})
                break;
            case 'price': this.setState({Price: e.target.value})
                break;
            case 'vendor': this.setState({Vendor: e.target.value})
                break;
        }
    }

    CloseHandler(){
        document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "none"
    }

    SaveHandler(){

    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="Modal-Background">
                <div className="Inventory-Modal">
                    <button className="ButtonInv1" style={{position: 'absolute', left: '95%', bottom: '93%', width: '35px'}} onClick={this.CloseHandler.bind(this)}>X</button>
                    <p style={{fontSize: "20px", borderBottom: '2px solid black', width: '33%', marginLeft: '33%', marginTop: '0', marginBottom: '2%'}}><b>Part Information</b></p>
                    <div className="ModalContent">
                        <div id="c1" style={{width: '33%', display: 'flex', marginTop: '4%'}}>
                            <div className="C1-1">
                                <p style={{margin: '0', marginBottom: '2%'}}>Part Name</p>
                                <br />
                                <p style={{margin: '0', marginBottom: '2%'}}>Type</p>
                                <br />
                                <p style={{margin: '0', marginBottom: '2%'}}>Vendor</p>
                                <br />
                                <p style={{margin: '0', marginBottom: '2%'}}>Location</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="C1-2">
                                <input style={{textAlign: 'center'}} type="text" id="partname" value={this.state.Partname} onChange={this.OnChangeHandler.bind(this)}></input>
                                <br />
                                <br />
                                <input style={{textAlign: 'center'}} id="type" disabled="true" value={this.state.Type}></input>
                                <br />
                                <br />
                                <input style={{textAlign: 'center'}} id="vendor" onChange={this.OnChangeHandler.bind(this)} value={this.state.Vendor}></input>
                                <br />
                                <br />
                                <input style={{textAlign: 'center'}} id="location" onChange={this.OnChangeHandler.bind(this)} value={this.state.Location}></input>
                            </div>                          
                        </div>

                        <div id="c2" style={{width: '33%'}}>
                            <p>Date Created</p>
                            <input style={{textAlign: 'center'}} id="datecreated" disabled="true" value={this.state.DateCreated}></input>
                            <p>Part Number</p>
                            <input style={{textAlign: 'center'}} id="partnumber" onChange={this.OnChangeHandler.bind(this)} value={this.state.PartNumber}></input>
                            <p>Model Number</p>
                            <input style={{textAlign: 'center'}} id="modelnumber" onChange={this.OnChangeHandler.bind(this)} value={this.state.ModelNumber}></input>
                            <p>Serial Number</p>
                            <input style={{textAlign: 'center'}} id="serialnumber" onChange={this.OnChangeHandler.bind(this)} value={this.state.Serial}></input>
                            <p style={{marginTop: '25%'}}>Description</p>
                            <textarea style={{width: '100%', height: '85px'}} id="description" onChange={this.OnChangeHandler.bind(this)} value={this.state.Description}></textarea>
                        </div>

                        <div id="c3" style={{width: '33%', display: 'flex', marginTop: '4%'}}> 
                            <div className="C3-2">
                                <input style={{textAlign: 'center'}} type="text" id="quantity" disabled="true" value={this.state.QuantityOnHand}></input>
                                <br />
                                <br />
                                <input style={{textAlign: 'center'}} id="price" onChange={this.OnChangeHandler.bind(this)} value={this.state.Price}></input>
                                <br />
                                <br />
                                <input style={{textAlign: 'center'}} id="units" disabled="true" value={this.state.Units}></input>
                                <br />
                                <br />
                                <input style={{textAlign: 'center'}} id="reorderpoint" onChange={this.OnChangeHandler.bind(this)} value={this.state.ReorderPoint}></input>
                            </div>
                            <div className="C3-1">
                                <p style={{margin: '0', marginBottom: '2%'}}>QTY</p>
                                <br />
                                <p style={{margin: '0', marginBottom: '2%'}}>Price</p>
                                <br />
                                <p style={{margin: '0', marginBottom: '2%'}}>Units</p>
                                <br />
                                <p style={{margin: '0', marginBottom: '2%'}}>Reorder Point</p>
                            </div>

                            <button className="ButtonInv1" style={{position: 'relative', top: '80%', right: '2%'}} onClick={this.SaveHandler.bind(this)}>Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

And here is the code that calls my modal

```js
import React from 'react'

class ViewAllItems extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
   super(props);

   this.state = {
    ItemList: this.props.ItemList,
    updateClickedRow: "",
    ItemToPass: "",
    ItemSelected: "",
   }
  }
RowClick(e){
        //console.log(e.target.id)
        var items = this.state.ItemList;

        for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
            if(items[i].ID == e.target.id){
                var Item = {
                    ID: items[i].ID,
                    CreatedBy: items[i].CreatedBy,
                    DateCreated: items[i].DateCreated,
                    Description: items[i].Description,
                    Location: items[i].Location,
                    ModelNumber: items[i].ModelNumber,
                    Serial: items[i].Serial,
                    PartNumber: items[i].PartNumber,
                    PartName: items[i].PartName,
                    Price: items[i].Price,
                    QuantityOnHand: items[i].QuantityOnHand,
                    ReorderPoint: items[i].ReorderPoint,
                    Type: items[i].Type,
                    Units: items[i].Units,
                    Vendor: items[i].Vendor,
                }
            }
        }

        this.setState({ updateClickedRow: e.target.id,
                        ItemToPass: Item,
        }); //Updates Left Column
        (document.getElementById('myModal')).style.display = "block";
    }

RenderTable2(){
        var items = this.state.ItemList;
        var rows = [];


        for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
            if(this.state.ItemSelected == "All Items"){
                rows.push(
                    <tr style={{backgroundColor: '#B7BCDF'}} id={items[i].ID} onClick={this.RowClick.bind(this)} key={i}>
                        <td style={{width: '111px'}} id={items[i].ID} onClick={this.RowClick.bind(this)}>
                            {items[i].PartName}
                        </td>

                        <td  style={{width: '94px'}} id={items[i].ID} onClick={this.RowClick.bind(this)}>
                            {items[i].Vendor}
                        </td>

                        <td  style={{width: '100px'}} id={items[i].ID} onClick={this.RowClick.bind(this)}>
                            {items[i].PartNumber}
                        </td>

                        <td  style={{width: '100px'}} id={items[i].ID} onClick={this.RowClick.bind(this)}>
                            {items[i].Price}
                        </td>

                        <td  style={{width: '100px'}} id={items[i].ID} onClick={this.RowClick.bind(this)}>
                            {items[i].QuantityOnHand}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                )
            }else if(this.state.ItemSelected == "Assembly Items"){
                if(items[i].Type == "Assembly Item"){
                    rows.push(
                        <tr style={{backgroundColor: '#B7BCDF'}} id={items[i].ID} onClick={this.RowClick.bind(this)} key={i}>
                            <td style={{width: '111px'}} id={items[i].ID} onClick={this.RowClick.bind(this)}>
                                {items[i].PartName}
                            </td>

                            <td  style={{width: '94px'}} id={items[i].ID} onClick={this.RowClick.bind(this)}>
                                {items[i].Vendor}
                            </td>

                            <td  style={{width: '100px'}} id={items[i].ID} onClick={this.RowClick.bind(this)}>
                                {items[i].Location}
                            </td>

                            <td  style={{width: '100px'}} id={items[i].ID} onClick={this.RowClick.bind(this)}>
                                {items[i].PartNumber}
                            </td>

                            <td  style={{width: '100px'}} id={items[i].ID} onClick={this.RowClick.bind(this)}>
                                {items[i].QuantityOnHand}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    )
                }   
            }

        }

        return (

            <div className="TableScroll">
                <table className="TableRows">
                    <tbody>
                        {rows}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

        );

    }

    RenderModal(){
        //console.log(this.state.ItemToPass);
        console.log("item passed to modal: " + JSON.stringify(this.state.ItemToPass));
        let item = this.state.ItemToPass;

        return(
            <InventoryModal item={item} /> 
        );
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="ViewAllItemsContainer">
                <div className="ViewAllDropdown">
                    <p style={{fontSize: "20px"}}><b>Select an Item</b></p>
                    <select style={{width: '200px', overflowY: 'scroll'}} id="ItemSelect" onChange={this.ItemSelected.bind(this)} value={this.state.ItemSelected}>
                        <option value="All Items"> All Items</option>
                        <option value="Assembly Items">Assembly Items</option>
                        {this.RenderOptions(this.props.ItemList)}
                    </select>
                    <br />
                    {this.KioskInput()}   
                </div>
                <br />
                <div className="CheckboxContainer"></div>

                <div id="myModal" style={{display: 'none'}}>
                    {this.RenderModal(this)}
                </div>


                <div className="InvTable" style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
                    {this.state.ItemSelected == "All Items" ? (
                        <table className="TableHeaderContainer" style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th style={{position: "relative", left: '1%'}}>Part Name</th>
                                <th style={{position: "relative", left: '5%'}}>Vendor</th>
                                <th style={{position: "relative", left: '5%'}}>Part Number</th>
                                <th style={{position: "relative", left: '8%'}}>Price</th>
                                <th style={{position: "relative", left: '6%'}}>Quantity on Hand</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        </table>
                    ) :
                    this.state.ItemSelected == "Assembly Items" ? (
                        <table className="TableHeaderContainer" style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th style={{position: "relative", left: '2%'}}>Part Name</th>
                                <th style={{position: "relative", left: '7%'}}>Vendor</th>
                                <th style={{position: "relative", left: '11%'}}>Location</th>
                                <th style={{position: "relative", left: '12%'}}>Part Number</th>
                                <th style={{position: "relative", left: '5%'}}>Quantity on Hand</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        </table>
                    ):
                    <table className="TableHeaderContainer">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th style={{position: 'relative', right: '1%'}}>Part Number</th>
                                <th style={{position: 'relative', right: '2%'}}>Created Date</th>
                                <th style={{position: 'relative', right: '5%'}}>Serial Number</th>
                                <th style={{position: 'relative', right: '8%'}}>Model Number</th>
                                <th style={{position: 'relative', right: '7%'}}>Vendor</th>
                                <th style={{position: 'relative', right: '3%'}}>Firmware</th>
                                <th>Phone</th>
                                <th>Part Status</th>
                                <th style={{position: 'relative', left: '2%'}}>Kiosk</th>
                                <th style={{position: 'relative', left: '2%'}}>Last Changed By</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                    }

                    {this.RenderTable2(this)}
                </div>
            </div>
        )



    }
}

export default ViewAllItems
```

This might not be the best way to go about this but if anyone has any ideas as to why this isn't working I would greatly appreciate it! Thanks.

Comment: can you please put you code on https://codesandbox.io/ or stackblitz ?

Comment: Do you get correct value if you log `this.props.item` in the `InventoryModal` constructor?

Comment: @PatrickEvans if you look at my state in my modal class I already do this by PartName: this.props.item.PartName

Comment: Yea read the initial state part wrong. Note you can shorten your code a lot by [using spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), eg `this.state = {...this.prop.item}`

Comment: @PatrickEvans on render of my ViewAllItems class I get a null string value, but after I click a row, nothing else get's logged.  I think this is because my modal is already being rendered once my ViewAllItems component is rendered.

Comment: Could you try to bind your modal directly to the state:   <InventoryModal item={this.state.ItemToPass} />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the state of `InventoryModal` when your `item` prop changes.

You can do this using [`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) in your `InventoryModal`:

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    if (this.props.item && prevState.ID !== this.props.item.ID) {
      const item = this.props.item;
      this.setState({
        Item: item,
        ID: item.ID,
        CreatedBy: item.CreatedBy,
        DateCreated: item.DateCreated,
        Description: item.Description,
        Location: item.Location,
        ModelNumber: item.ModelNumber,
        Serial: item.Serial,
        PartNumber: item.PartNumber,
        PartName: item.PartName,
        Price: item.Price,
        QuantityOnHand: item.QuantityOnHand,
        ReorderPoint: item.ReorderNumber,
        Type: item.Type,
        Units: item.Units,
        Vendor: item.Vendor
      });
    }
  }
```